# In chainer, how to write BPTT updater using trainer exactly?

Tags: python, chainer

chainer document RNN tutorial has incorrect code in this page:
 https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/recurrentnet.html

```
def update_bptt(updater):
    loss = 0
    for i in range(35):
        batch = train_iter.__next__()
        x, t = chainer.dataset.concat_examples(batch)
        loss += model(chainer.Variable(x), chainer.Variable(t))

    model.cleargrads()
    loss.backward()
    loss.unchain_backward()  # truncate
    optimizer.update()

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, **update_bptt**)
```

the training.StandardUpdater 3rd parameter is converter=concat_example, not update function.
How to write BPTT using trainer exactly?

Comment: I'm also not sure about the document above. But you can refer chainer official example, it has sample implementation of BPTTUpdater.

https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/ptb/train_ptb.py

Comment: Because chainer.training.ParallelUpdater has ability to train on multiple GPU, how to add this ability to BPTT updater. This example didn't show this.

Comment: @corochann 

How to write BPTT updater using multiple GPUs? I don't find example because exsiting method only extends training.StandardUpdater, thus only use One GPU.